# Open ports on my router's guest network?

Tags: nmap, router

I've created an open guest network on my router (N600 Wireless Dual Band Gigabit Router Model No. TL-WDR3600 v1, 3.14.3 Build 150518 Rel.72050n). Internally nmap gives me:

```
Nmap scan report for 192.168.0.1
Host is up (0.041s latency).
Not shown: 992 closed ports
PORT      STATE    SERVICE
21/tcp    filtered ftp
22/tcp    filtered ssh
80/tcp    filtered http
139/tcp   filtered netbios-ssn
445/tcp   filtered microsoft-ds
1041/tcp  filtered danf-ak2
1900/tcp  open     upnp
49152/tcp open     unknown
```

I don't understand why any of the ports are listed. When I use nmap on my secure wifi network I see:

```
Nmap scan report for 192.168.0.1
Host is up (0.044s latency).
Not shown: 996 closed ports
PORT      STATE SERVICE
22/tcp    open  ssh
80/tcp    open  http
1900/tcp  open  upnp
49152/tcp open  unknown
```

Didn't even know my router had ssh capabilities... Why is FTP showing on the guest network? How to find out what 49152 is?

Comment: I read the manual for your router, and it explains everything: http://www.downloads.netgear.com/files/WNDRMAC_UM_15Apr11.pdf You are seeing the 'Readyshare' options being open on the guest network. It explains the ftp, http, and ports 139 and 445.

Comment: port 49152 is the SDDP - if you search "netgear port 49152" you will get lots to look through

Comment: Thanks @schroeder, I'm too lowly to say thank you in any other way ;-)

Answer (score 1):

These are open services on your network 
Port 49152: As the first port in the dynamic/private range (49152-65535), this port is commonly used by applications that utilize a dynamic/random/configurable port.

uTorrent, and Azureus/Vuze p2p torrent clients often use this port.

Apple Xsan Filesystem Access uses the dynamic/private range 49152-65535 as well.

Answer (score 0):

Are there any network services that you use? For example do you have a web server on your network? Do you ever use SSH to connect to a computer behind your router? If not you can disable NAT on ports 80 and 22 respectively. Here is a [list of standard ports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers) that you can use a reference. I would recommend looking up all ports that are showing on your network, and disabling all services that you don't use. The more ports you have open, the more potential attack vectors there are on your network, especially unfiltered ports.